# Compare range of values. Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets

As of now, I would like to compare a range of values (different rows but same cells) and highlight them according to the result.

Let's say that we have Row A with some numbers and Row B also with numbers.

```
A   B
10  5
20  30
30  40
```

I would like to use conditional formatting to highlight cells in Row B if they are greater than in Row A. Like iterate through each of them, compare A1 < B1 (A2 < B2.. A"X" < B"X") and highlight each of them if the cell is greater.

Could you support me on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that

> Go to Format > [Conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) > format cell if... and Choose Custom formula. and **Paste** this formula in "Value or Formula". take a look at the **[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xv0K-mskjd-kNo2XscIIOo2KzhUPQm4MzGVQfHrmJbU/edit?usp=sharing)**.

```
=IF(A2:A="",,B2:B>A2:A)
```

[image: Conditional formatting]

**Explanation**

[`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) Range `A2:A` is Empty `""` Do nothing `,,` if isn't Empty check if `B2:B > A2:A` if TRUE Highlight green if FALSE do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in `Custom formula is`

```
=B1>A1
```

OR (to take into account empty cells in column `A`)

```
=AND(B1>A1,A1<>"")
```